# how to make a fixed size grid column with Auto as the value

Tags: wpf, grid

I created a simple Radio Button style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border x:Name="BORDER_PART" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" BorderThickness="0.5" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LABEL_PART" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BORDER_PART" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="BORDER_PART" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5 0.5 0.5 0"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="LABEL_PART" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="LABEL_PART" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="BORDER_PART" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

then I apply it in a grid like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" GroupName="TabNavigator" IsChecked="True" Content="Home" />
    <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" GroupName="TabNavigator" Content="Dashboard"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="moveAroundTextBlock" Text="some text" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 0 5"/>

    <Button Content="Help" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Button Content="Close" Grid.Column="4" />
</Grid>
```

as you can see in the style, when the radiobutton is hovered by the mouse, the text will become bold, it's all good, but when it applied in a grid like above, the 'moveAroundTextBlock' will looks like it moved everytime the radiobutton switching between bold and regular since the column where the radiobutton stays is marked as auto (it's a requirement though due to the possibilities of localization to other languages so the text wont be cut off)

so the question is:
How do i make the 'moveAroundTextBlock' stay still in its position with the following restriction:
- columns for the radio buttons and the buttons must be auto
- the moveAroundTextBlock must be centered horizontally in its column

(or in other word, how to make the column for the raidobuttons doesnt get wider when the content is Bold while preserving the Auto sized columns)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want the columns width to be determined by the width of the content, yet you want them to remain unchanged when the contents width is changed...isn't that a bit contradicting?

Comment: I don't think this is a good practice to change the font for a selected tab, you should better change the background or borderBrush. Change anything that don't modify the actual size of the controls. Solution for your example will be using a converter that will calculate the width of textblock in bold weight and bind that width for both the checked and unchecked state, but this is very ugly.

Comment: @Eirik : err yeah I think that's what I want, and when you said it that way, it sounds contradicting :D.

Comment: @NovitchiS : yeah, currently i change the border brush instead, though I really want to make it bold.